# Time Input Pattern 12hrs

Tags: html, regex, input, time

I have to make an HTML input pattern that accepts only date and 12hrs time in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm AM/PM 
so far i've come up with this expression

```
<input type='text' name='a' pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] (2[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)' required>
```

This accpets the input as 2016-12-22 1:50 AM 
i want is to accept 2 digits for the time 
like 01,06,12 etc. 
Is this Possible ?

Comment: Do you mean the leading `0` is required for hours? Replace `(2[012]|[1-9])` with `(2[0-3]|0[1-9])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be `1[012]` instead of  `2[012]` (Hour = 10, 11, 12 and not 20, 21, 22):

```
pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)'
```

To make it require a `0`:

```
pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] (1[012]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)'
```

To make the `0` optional:

```
pattern='[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] (1[012]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)'
```

Comment: Sorry I was testing it with a 2 so accidentely posted it here.